AWS CDK building a docker image
I'm currently using AWS CDK to test building out a docker image and pushing it to ECR. From what I've gathered, this is the constructs that I'm using:
user = iam.User(self, 'User')
ecr.PublicGalleryAuthorizationToken.grant_read(user)

image = ecr_assets.DockerImageAsset(self, "TestBuildImage",
                                    directory="./src")

I have docker installed locally, and docker desktop is running, but I still get this error:
CdkBatchS3GlueTestStack:  fail: Unable to execute 'docker' in order to build a container asset. Please install 'docker' and try again.
Am I missing something that I should be doing?

does the docker command work from the same terminal where you're executing cdk deploy?

you could also check that your system user is part of the docker group

@gshpychka Yes, the docker command works in the same terminal. I can even run docker image build on the same folder that should be turning into an image.

@therealdakotal What do you mean?

Not sure about windows, but if you're on macos or linux, you can't run direct docker commands right after installing the CLI. You have to add your user to the docker group otherwise you have to sudo all of your docker commands. You can check by running groups and verifying docker is in the list. But if you can run docker image build like you mentioned in your previous comment, you probably already have the needed permissions.  So this likely isn't the fix.
